# Programmatically set the tomcat jvmRoute

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, load-balancing

I have started 6 Tomcat containers on Docker.

I don't want to go into the individual containers to set the `jvmRoute` property in `server.xml` for each of them.

How can I programmatically set the `jvmRoute` , if say, I want to name the `jvmRoute` property as `Tomcat1 -> Tomcat9` (or using other convention)

Comment: Is picking up the name (or part of it) from an environment variable an option?

Comment: Apologies. I just saw this. What would it look like if I were to pick it up from environment variables. I will know if it is what I want.

Comment: Sorry. Should have said Java system property. If you set a system property when the process starts via -Dfoo=bar then you can use that in server.xml as jvmRoute="${foo}" and that gets translated to jvmRoute="bar" by Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Can I set this system property at my own app startup time or  do I have to write the java code and ensure tomcat runs it at its own startup?

Comment: You just add -Dfoo=bar to the command line that starts the java process that Tomcat uses.

Comment: I can't set this from my java code, can I? I don't want to make any input again when starting the process. I am creating the tomcat containers with docker-compose.

Comment: @Mark Thomas , what would you suggest if my tomcat cluster grew very large and I have to automate assigning ```jvmRoute``` values to the different instances. It would be unpleasant to log into each of the containers and assign ```jvmRoute``` values to them right?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to summarize this from the comments above. You can control the jvmRoute property from outside with an environment variable that you pass to your docker container. Actually, I was having the same problem in Kubernetes came to the following solution:

In the server.xml I did set the following attribute on the Engine tag:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="${node_routing_suffix}">
```

Then, in the setenv.sh script I added this:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="${CATALINA_OPTS} -Dnode_routing_suffix=${NODE_ROUTING_SUFFIX}"
```

Now I can pass the env variable NODE_ROUTING_SUFFIX to my container to set the jvmRoute.

Comment: `"${node_routing_suffix:-}"` ensures `jvmRoute` is not set if the variable isn't set. This is useful if you're using the same server.xml elsewhere without load balancing.